# structure of database of Ms project server 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

I am working on a project of interaction between Ms project server 2010 And Google aps
what i had to do is :
every time you add a task on Ms project server and you assign to someone ( by adding his resource to the task) ... the task should appear his Google agenda

what i need to do is read some specific attribute from database of Ms project server 2010 ( such as name of task,when it starts , name of project ..) ,
but when i open the database using sql server i found that it contains lot of tables , 
i want to know if there s any documents that explain the whole structure (MCD) and data dictionary .

and thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Draft, Published and Reporting databases. But only Reporting is documented and recommended by Microsoft for direct access. You can find its schema in Project 2010 SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15511

Other option is using Project Server event handlers and PSI.

Comment: Maxim is spot on, plus if you do go off the reservation and directly interact with the Draft or Published databases, you run the risk of rendering your installation unsupportable by Microsoft.  I was on the MCS team responsible for Project Server for a few years--more than once we had to turn away support requests because of this.

Use the PSI is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a document for you... but I do have some code you may find helpful:

[MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) provides a database reader which will read project data from  MS Project MPD databases, and Project Server SQL Server databases (they share a very similar structure). You can either use MPXJ itself abstract the mechanics of reading the data from the database, or you can dive in to the source to see how the tables and columns work, then produce your own queries.

If you want to take the latter approach, you'll find the select statements from the various tables live in the [MPD9DatabaseReader](http://sourceforge.net/p/mpxj/mpxj/ci/master/tree/src/net/sf/mpxj/mpd/MPD9DatabaseReader.java) class. The result sets are processed in the [MPDAbstractReader](http://sourceforge.net/p/mpxj/mpxj/ci/master/tree/src/net/sf/mpxj/mpd/MPD9AbstractReader.java) class.